# Save checkout custom field value and display it in WooCommerce admin orders

Tags: php, woocommerce, dropdown, checkout, custom-fields

I have some additional fields in my checkout for asking questions from the customer about certain things regarding their order. Most of these are text input fields but there's one Select menu asking them how they heard about my clients site. I've been unable to figure out how to display the value in the meta area of the order for the selected option. Here's how I'm generating that select drop down in my functions.php file from my theme.

```
woocommerce_form_field( 'aba_hear', array(
    'type'     => 'select',
    'required' => 'true',
    'class'    => array('hear-class form-row-wide'),
    'label'    => __('How did You Hear About Us&#63;'),
    'options'  => array( // options for <select> or <input type="radio" />
        ''          => 'Please select', // empty values means that field is not selected
        'Instagram' => 'Instagram',
        'Facebook'  => 'Facebook',
        'Yelp'  => 'Yelp',
        'Other' => 'Other',
    )

), $checkout->get_value( 'aba_hear' ) );
```

Now I go add a function to update the order meta values:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'aba_checkout_field_update_order_meta' );

function aba_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['aba_hear'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'How did You Hear About Us&#63;', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['aba_hear'] ) );
    }
}
```

And finally display the value on the order page:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'aba_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );
function aba_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta($order){
    echo '<p><strong>'.__('How did You Hear About Us&#63;').':</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->id, 'Is this a Gift&#63;', true ) . '</p>';
}
```

Lastly here's how the select menu's code appears at checkout:

```html
<p class="form-row hear-class form-row-wide validate-required" id="aba_hear_field" data-priority="">
    <label for="aba_hear" class="">How did You Hear About Us&#063;&nbsp;<abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr></label>
    <span class="woocommerce-input-wrapper">
        <select name="aba_hear" id="aba_hear" class="select " data-allow_clear="true" data-placeholder="Please select">
            <option value=""  selected='selected'>Please select</option>
            <option value="Instagram" >Instagram</option>
            <option value="Facebook" >Facebook</option>
            <option value="Yelp" >Yelp</option>
            <option value="Other" >Other</option>
        </select>
    </span>
</p>
```

Now, this works fine for text input fields but not select menus. How can I change this to make it work so I can display the resulting data?

Comment: You're using `update_post_meta( $order_id, 'How did You Hear About Us&#63;',..` and `get_post_meta( $order->id, 'Is this a Gift&#63;',..` so your `meta_key` certainly does NOT match. It is also recommended to use a meta_key without spaces. 
In any case, there are several examples of how you can add a select field to the checkout page and then display in order pages. By example: [Add a new custom field to WooCommerce checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61208520/add-a-new-custom-field-to-woocommerce-checkout).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some mistakes in some of your functions… You need to use the same checkout field key as meta key in the following functions:

In the 2nd function, you use another hook and save custom field as user meta data too:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'aba_checkout_field_update_order_meta' );

function aba_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order ) {
    if ( isset($_POST['aba_hear']) && ! empty($_POST['aba_hear']) ) {
        $order->update_meta_data( '_aba_hear', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['aba_hear'] ) );

        // Update user data
        if( $order->get_user_id() > 0 ) {
            update_user_meta( $order->get_user_id(), 'aba_hear', true );
        }
    }
}
```

In the 3rd function use this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'aba_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1 );
function aba_checkout_field_display_admin_order_meta( $order ){
    $value = $order->get_meta( '_aba_hear' );

    if ( ! empty($value) ) {
        echo '<p><strong>'.__('How did You Hear About Us&#63;').':</strong> ' . $value . '</p>';
    }
}
```

It should better work now.

---

> #### Notes:
>
> **Why saving this checkout field also as custom user meta data?**
>
> Because in your first function you have `$checkout->get_value( 'aba_hear' )` that will display the selected value on from customer last order in this custom checkout field. The value is read from user meta 'aba_hear'.

Comment: It works although for some reason, I keep getting Internal Service Error at Checkout even though the order goes through.

Comment: Seems to be at the top of the 2nd Function where the debug log says "Undefined variable: order_id". Which is interesting, because I never call on order_id anywhere in that file.

Comment: @Jose No sorry as `$order->save()` is included just after `woocommerce_checkout_create_order` hook in WC_Checkout create_order() method…

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I tested it. Without $order->save() it doesn't work, including $order->save() it works for me with WooCommerce v. 8.2.2.

Comment: @Jose Sorry it works without, see it [in the WooCommerce Source code](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/8.2/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-checkout.php#L446-L449) … just after `do_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order', $order, $data);`you have `$order_id = $order->save();`… So if you add it in the function the `save()` method run twice… END.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec if you write the function as in this answer, after do_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', $order, $data ); the object $order will not be what you have inside the function aba_checkout_field_update_order_meta. You should return the $order object inside the function, or add $order-save(). I invite you to test it. I've tested exactly the same hook, and I can ensure you, it doesn't work if you don't add $order->save().

Comment: No sorry, you are wrong!… I have a lot of [working accepted answer using this hook](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a3730754%20woocommerce_checkout_create_order&searchOn=3) (+/- 120 answers) without using `save()` method. Also, only filter hooks need to return the main argument, not action hooks…

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Have you tested it? Test it, and you will discover that it doesn't work. A lot of accepted answers doesn't mean it works, it means most people don't test the code before voting. My comment is to help other people who have problems trying your answer not to say that it's not a good answer. It's a good answer, but it misses an important line of code which is $order->save(). And that's it. Again, test it.

Comment: My code is always tested before publishing, unless I mention untested… And this answer code work as it's… END.