Woocommerce custom product fields
I've created custom fields in the woocommerce product using acf, all works as expected except for saving the custom fields against the order and showing at checkout.
I have tried the following code:
// Add shortcode to display venue information
function display_venue_information_shortcode() {
    ob_start(); // Start output buffering
    // Get the current product ID
    global $product;
    $product_id = $product->get_id();

    // Check if product ID is valid
    if ($product_id) {
        // Get the venue information associated with the product
        $venues = get_field('venues', $product_id);

        // Check if venues exist
        if ($venues) {
            // Output venue selection form
            ?>
            <form id="venue_information_form">
                <label for="venue">Select Venue:</label>
                <select name="venue" id="venue_select">
                    <option value="">Select Venue</option>
                    <?php foreach ($venues as $venue) : ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo esc_attr($venue['venue']->ID); ?>"><?php echo esc_html($venue['venue']->post_title); ?></option>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </select>
                <label for="date_time">Select Date & Time:</label>
                <select name="date_time" id="date_time_select">
                    <option value="">Select Date & Time</option>
                </select>
            </form>
            <script>
                // JavaScript to populate date/time options based on selected venue
                document.getElementById('venue_select').addEventListener('change', function() {
                    var venueId = this.value;
                    var dateSelect = document.getElementById('date_time_select');
                    // Clear previous options
                    dateSelect.innerHTML = '<option value="">Select Date & Time</option>';
                    // Get selected venue
                    var selectedVenue = this.options[this.selectedIndex].text;
                    // Get dates for the selected venue
                    var dates = <?php echo json_encode($venues); ?>;
                    if (venueId) {
                        dates.forEach(function(venue) {
                            if (venue.venue.ID == venueId) {
                                venue.dates.forEach(function(date) {
                                    dateSelect.innerHTML += '<option value="' + date['date_&_time'] + '">' + date['date_&_time'] + '</option>';
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            </script>
            <?php
        } else {
            // If no venues are found
            echo '<p>No venue information available.</p>';
        }
    }

    return ob_get_clean(); // Return the buffered output
}
add_shortcode('display_venue_information', 'display_venue_information_shortcode');

// Save venue and date against the order
function save_venue_and_date_to_order($order_id) {
    if (!empty($_POST['venue'])) {
        $venue = sanitize_text_field($_POST['venue']);
        update_post_meta($order_id, 'Selected Venue', $venue);
        WC()->session->set('selected_venue', $venue); // Store in session
    }

    if (!empty($_POST['date_time'])) {
        $date_time = sanitize_text_field($_POST['date_time']);
        update_post_meta($order_id, 'Selected Date & Time', $date_time);
        WC()->session->set('selected_date_time', $date_time); // Store in session
    }

    // Debugging
    error_log('Selected Venue: ' . WC()->session->get('selected_venue'));
    error_log('Selected Date & Time: ' . WC()->session->get('selected_date_time'));
}
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'save_venue_and_date_to_order');


// Add custom fields to the checkout page
function add_custom_checkout_fields() {
    echo '<div id="venue_information_checkout">';
    woocommerce_form_field('selected_venue', array(
        'type' => 'text',
        'class' => array('selected-venue-field form-row-wide'),
        'label' => __('Selected Venue'),
        'placeholder' => __(''),
        'required' => false,
        'readonly' => true,
    ), WC()->session->get('selected_venue')); // Populate with session value

    woocommerce_form_field('selected_date_time', array(
        'type' => 'text',
        'class' => array('selected-date-time-field form-row-wide'),
        'label' => __('Selected Date & Time'),
        'placeholder' => __(''),
        'required' => false,
        'readonly' => true,
    ), WC()->session->get('selected_date_time')); // Populate with session value
    echo '</div>';
}
add_action('woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'add_custom_checkout_fields');


// Populate custom fields with selected venue and date
function populate_custom_checkout_fields($order) {
    $selected_venue = get_post_meta($order->get_id(), 'Selected Venue', true);
    $selected_date_time = get_post_meta($order->get_id(), 'Selected Date & Time', true);

    echo '<div id="venue_information_checkout">';
    echo '<p><strong>Selected Venue:</strong> ' . $selected_venue . '</p>';
    echo '<p><strong>Selected Date & Time:</strong> ' . $selected_date_time . '</p>';
    echo '</div>';
}
add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'populate_custom_checkout_fields', 10, 1);

// Store selected venue and date in session
function store_selected_venue_and_date_to_session() {
    if (!empty($_POST['venue'])) {
        WC()->session->set('selected_venue', sanitize_text_field($_POST['venue']));
    }

    if (!empty($_POST['date_time'])) {
        WC()->session->set('selected_date_time', sanitize_text_field($_POST['date_time']));
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'store_selected_venue_and_date_to_session', 10, 1);



The select fields work as expected and when a venue is selected, the available dates are shown. But it doesnt seem to pass this information to the order and show at either checkout or against the order in backend.

Data wont show automaticaly. Debug order and you will prob see the data you are looking for. Keep in mind orders have limited hooks and lack big customizations. Here is example - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65606400/save-checkout-custom-field-value-and-display-it-in-woocommerce-admin-orders . WC()->session->set you set field to session instead of  saving it in order.
